# Fluent Api: one to zero or one on both ends

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship, ef-fluent-api

How do you configure a one to zero or one relationship one both sides. For example:

```
public class Student{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public Registration Registration {get; set;}
}

public class Registration{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  //public int StudentId {get; set;}
  public Student StudentEntity {get; set;}
}
```

A student can exist without a registration; and a registration can be created without a student. I am able to configure Registration  like

```
HasOptional(o => o.StudentEntity).WithOptionalDependent(d => d.Registration ).Map(p => p.MapKey("StudentId"));
```

But this requires that I remove the StudentId property from my model. I however need this in order to update the relationship. How can I therefore configure such relationship and keep my foreignkey defined in the model?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in an one to one relationship both entities, the principal and the dependent, must share the same PK, and the primary key of the dependent also has to be the foreign key:

```
public class Principal
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Dependent Dependent{get;set;}
}

public class Dependent
{
  [Key,ForeignKey("Principal")]
  public int PrincipalId {get;set;}
  public virtual Principal Principal{get;set;}
}
```

There is not other way to map the FK in an one to one relationship in EF.

Seeing your model maybe what you really need is an one to many relationship.I think an student could be registered more than one time, in that case your model would be:

```
public class Student{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations {get; set;}
}

public class Registration{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int StudentId {get; set;}
  public Student StudentEntity {get; set;}
}
```

And the relationship configuration would be:

```
HasOptional(o => o.StudentEntity).WithMany(d => d.Registrations).HasForeignKey(o=>o.StudentId);
```